# How should I write a regex to to find an expression that might include numbers?

Tags: regex

Hi Im new to work with the regex syntax and trying to extract a result of a number which come right after a constant text form html, such as:

"distance to destination: 234" - "distance to destination:" is constant and the number might appear and not appear at all.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please, show what you've tried. And give more examples and expected result.

Comment: Please also indicate what version of regular expressions you will be using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use some simple regex like this one: `distance to destination: ([0-9]{0,10})`.

It will return 1 group with the number. Note this number may have in between 0 and 10 digits `{0,10}`.

You can test it and practice further editions in any online regex tester website, like this one I personally use: https://regex101.com/